# Registration page in string, handle data from the JSON and response something?

Tags: json, spring, jakarta-ee

My task is to create user account in Spring. This is an excerpt from `index.jsp`.

Submitting to `/register` sends Name, Surname, Login and Email using POST. My task is to receive this data and send it to the database. When data is registered in database I must return status code: "1" for success or "0" if no users were added.

When I execute `/register` I have information that *"Required param GET"*. What is the problem?

```
<div id="register">
   <div class="top-bar">
      <header class="page-title">Zarządzanie projektami studenckimi</header>
   </div>
   <header class="section-title">Rejestracja</header>
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr> <td colspan="2" class="info" /> </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="param">Imię:</td>
         <td class="value">
            <input type="text" id="register-firstname" />
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="param">Nazwisko:</td>
         <td class="value">
            <input type="text" id="register-surname" />
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="param">Adres email:</td>
         <td class="value">
            <input type="text" id="register-email" />
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="param">Nazwa użytkownika:</td>
         <td class="value">
            <input type="text" id="register-user" />
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style="text-align: left;" />
         <td style="text-align: right;">
            <input type="button" id="register-button" value="Zarejestruj" />
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

And this is my code from the `logincontroller.java` in `Spring`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Integer addProwadzacy(
        @RequestParam(value = "firstname", required = true) String imie,
        @RequestParam(value = "surname", required = true) String nazwisko,
        @RequestParam(value = "email", required = true) String mail,
        @RequestParam(value = "user", required = true) String login,
        Model model) {

    Date data = new Date();
    String haslo = null;
    // RandomPassword.
    Prowadzacy prowadzacy = new Prowadzacy();
    prowadzacy.setImiona(imie);
    prowadzacy.setNazwisko(nazwisko);
    prowadzacy.setEmail(mail);
    prowadzacy.setLogin(login);
    prowadzacy.setDataDodania(data);
    prowadzacy.setWaznosc(true);
    prowadzacy.setAktywowany(false);
    prowadzacy.setHaslo(Encryption.encrypt(haslo));
    loginService.addProwadzacy(prowadzacy);

    List<Prowadzacy> registerlist = loginService.validateRegister(imie,
            nazwisko, mail, login);
    if (registerlist.size() > 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something not working?

Comment: I don't have information from registration page in database and  have't got in response 0 or 1 .

Comment: Then your database insertion code doesn't work. Getting any exceptions?

Comment: I think that maybe the problem with the setting start page and put information in good url? Don't have any exception.

Comment: Now working. I have a problem with the URL: both in my server and in js file.

Comment: Where is the code that submits the form? Where is the exact stack trace? Surely there's more than *"Required param GET"* ?. Use Firebug (or Chrome's developer tools) and check the Network tab, investigate the request sent when you click "submit" (if any). Does it use the right method? Does it contain the required parameters?